# how can I read a value from an environment variable with ':' in its name?

Tags: bash, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using elastic beanstalk. Some values are environment properties of the environment. When I perform a `container_command` I'm able to read this properties as environment variables. The problem is the following: a lot of properties are named like this `db:user` or `collector:server` and after that the value.

How can I read this values? I can interpret them as environment variables. So the environment properties with 'normal' names I can read. But not those ones who contain a ':' in their name:

To test (+ make it clearer for people who don't know elastic beanstalk) I've created this. The global goal is to read the value of a variable which contains a ':' in its name.

```
#!/bin/bash

${myvar:test}="hey" 
echo ${myvar:test}

$./test.sh
$./test.sh: line 3: =hey: command not found
```

Comment: As for `${myvar:test}="hey" `, it isn't a valid assignment. It doesn't actually create a variable at all. Colons **are not valid** in shell variable names.

Comment: (Yes, they're allowable in environment variable names, but the shell is allowed to discard those environment variables, and many shells -- including some widely-used versions of bash -- do so).

Comment: (note that by "discard those environment variables" above, I don't just mean fail to convert them to shell variables -- *every* POSIX-compliant shell will fail to convert them to shell variables -- but I mean actually removing them from the environment; fortunately, procfs shows the environment as it was at process startup time, as opposed to as it is presently).

Answer (score 0):

`:` isn't an allowed character in shell variables at all, and `${test:foo}` has a completely separate meaning (it expands `$test` with a default value of `foo` if no variable named `test` is defined).

If your operating system is Linux, however, you can directly parse your original environment variables from procfs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A env=( )   ## <- note that this requires bash 4.0 or newer

while IFS= read -r -d '' envvar; do
  [[ $envvar = *:* ]] || continue
  varname=${envvar%%=*}
  value=${envvar#*=}
  env[$varname]=$value
done < /proc/self/environ

echo "The value of the environment variable db:user is: <<${env[db:user]}>>"
```

---

Note that to test this, though, you'll need to be able to actually **create** an environment variable with a literal colon, and your code currently fails at doing so. Consider instead:

```
env db:user="test value for db:user" ./yourscript
```